# Angularjs. $resource change encoding to ISO-8859-1, but server sent in utf-8

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, iso-8859-1, angular-resource

i have a trouble)
From angularjs i send data into my server using next service

```
    app.factory("SpeakerEditService", function ($resource) {
    return $resource('url',
        {
            speakerId: '@id',
            firstName: "@firstName",
            middleName: "@middleName",
            lastName: "@lastName",
            organisation: '@organisation'
        },
        {
            update: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray:false,
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }
        }
    )
})
```

And my controller:

```
$scope.edit = function edit(row) {
        SpeakerEditService.update({}, row.entity)
    }
```

And in app.js configuration:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

but to server data comes like this^
[image]

And server works only with utf-8
[image]

What i'm doing wrong?